# Confusing about <security-role> in web.xml

Tags: java, database, tomcat, web.xml, realm

I'm understand that 
`<security-role><role-name>Admin</role-name></security-role>` 
is for container map it with tomcat-users.xml  (realm)

but I confuse about if I didn't use realm but I use database how container know which field in my database is for role-name or it have naming convention in database field name like "role_name" and container will know it

Thank you for every advices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a database realm and configure the table and column names in a `<Realm>` element in server configuration file. For Tomcat, this is described in the [Realm HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html). Here's an extract of relevance, from the [JDBCRealm chapter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm):

> ### Quick Start
>
> To set up Tomcat to use JDBCRealm, you will need to follow these steps:
>
> 1. If you have not yet done so, create tables and columns in your
>      database that conform to the
>      requirements described above.
> 2. Configure a database username and password for use by Tomcat, that
>      has at least read only access to the
>      tables described above. (Tomcat will
>      never attempt to write to these
>      tables.)
> 3. Place a copy of the JDBC driver you will be using inside the
>      `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory. Note
>      that only JAR files are recognized!
> 4. Set up a `<Realm>` element, as described below, in your
>      `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` file.
> 5. Restart Tomcat 6 if it is already running.
>
> #### Realm Element Attributes
>
> To configure JDBCRealm, you will
>   create a `<Realm>` element and nest it
>   in your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`
>   file, as described above. The
>   attributes for the JDBCRealm are
>   defined in the Realm configuration
>   documentation.
>
> #### Example
>
> An example SQL script to create the
>   needed tables might look something
>   like this (adapt the syntax as
>   required for your particular
>   database):
>
> ```
> create table users (
>   user_name         varchar(15) not null primary key,  
>   user_pass         varchar(15) not null
> );
>
> create table user_roles (
>   user_name         varchar(15) not null,
>   role_name         varchar(15) not null,
>   primary key(user_name, role_name)
> );
> ```
>
> Example `Realm` elements are included
>   (commented out) in the default
>   `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` file.
>   Here's an example for using a MySQL
>   database called "authority",
>   configured with the tables described
>   above, and accessed with username
>   "dbuser" and password "dbpass":
>
> ```
> <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
>       driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"  
>    connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/authority?user=dbuser&amp;password=dbpass"
>        userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"   
>    userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name"/>
> ```

Pretty clear, isn't it? If you already have a JDBC datasource configured in Tomcat (for connection pooling and on), then you can also use [DataSourceRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#DataSourceRealm) instead.

The `tomcat-users.xml` which you're talking about is by the way called [UserDatabaseRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#UserDatabaseRealm).