# Tomcat user has principal role but request.isUserInRole() says otherwise

Tags: java, jsp, security, tomcat, jakarta-ee

In tomcat-users.xml is defined user and roles:

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="user,admin,APP_ADMIN"/>
  <role rolename="user"/>
  <role rolename="APP_ADMIN"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
```

and application security is defined as:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>Dynamic pages</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
                <description>These are the roles who have access.</description>
                <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
                <description></description>
                <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
```

But when I login as admin into application it gives me always HTTP 403 not authorized.

I checked roles with JSP scriplet:

```
out.write(request.getUserPrincipal().toString());
```

And it prints:

> User username="admin", roles="user,admin,APP_ADMIN"

But when i check isUserInRole:

```
out.write(request.isUserInRole("APP_ADMIN") ? "Yep" : "nope");
```

Gets:

> nope

Tomcat version is 7.0.55

Comment: Have you also defined the roles?

Comment: Hi, yes I added them to question.

Comment: Ooookey. Did you configure the memory realm too?

Comment: Yep that one is defined as well, also i can login with password admin-admin if i type wrong pass it doesnt log me in, so its look like it is loading tomcat-users.xml

Comment: Then I'm not quite sure :( I recommend you post the relevant part of your `server.xml` and `tomcat-users.xml` as well, maybe someone else will have something.

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the role in the XML to ROLE_APP_ADMIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the problem, i just had to replace lines in server.xml:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

with these:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
               <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>
```

Now I don't know why UserDatabaseRealm doesn't work without LockOutRealm wrapper, strange but its working now ...

Answer (score 2):

1: You might have to define the roles in the web.xml. See this SO Question [Why do I list security roles in web.xml when they're in jdbcRealm database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223318/why-do-i-list-security-roles-in-web-xml-when-theyre-in-jdbcrealm-database).

2: The wildcard '*' in the role-name could be causing trouble. Maybe give it a try with role-name 'user' and see if it works.

For a wildcard as role name you have to enable `allRolesMode`:

> This attribute controls how the special role name * is handled when
>   processing authorization constraints in web.xml. By default, the
>   specification compliant value of strict is used which means that the
>   user must be assigned one of the roles defined in web.xml. The
>   alternative values are authOnly which means that the user must be
>   authenticated but no check is made for assigned roles and
>   strictAuthOnly which means that the user must be authenticated and no
>   check will be made for assigned roles unless roles are defined in
>   web.xml in which case the user must be assigned at least one of those
>   roles.

See the Tomcat docs for more: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/realm.html